Is it possible to get accurate readings from stderr/stdout using boost::process?
Here's sample MS compiler output:

The first three lines are always printed to stderr, followed by usage line printed to stdout. cmd.exe is the interpreting shell that runs the cl.exe process, reads stderr/stdout from it and draws the text to the console output. It always outputs it in this order, without ever stdout appearing ahead of stderr (perhaps, they do fflush(stderr) before printing usage line).
If I use boost::process no matter what I tried, it pretty much always didn't match output order of what cmd.exe was showing.
I use this sample program to produce output:
/// test-exe.exe
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int lineLen = 1024;
    int stdoutCount = 5;
    int stderrCount = 5;
    int repeatCount = 10;

    std::string s;
    s.resize(lineLen);
    for (int i = 0; i < lineLen; ++i)
        s[i] = '0' + (i / 10) % 10;

    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; ++i)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stdoutCount; ++i)
            fprintf(stdout, "stdout %d %s\n", n++, s.c_str());
        for (int i = 0; i < stderrCount; ++i)
            fprintf(stderr, "stderr %d %s\n", n++, s.c_str());
    }
}

How to properly do that with boost::process::child so that combined output would match what gets shown with regular cmd prompt?
One way is to use boost::process::system and redirect stderr to stdout (eg system("test.exe 2>&1")), but that's a workaround, since the streams are processed by cmd.exe under the hood and I get combined stdout without any distinction if something is stdout or stderr.
I used this code as starting point and tried to modify it in different ways, but it didn't work for me. It doesn't get deadlocked reading lines from stdout/stderr, but the output order doesn't get preserved the same way as cmd.exe gets it.
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct OutputLine
{
    std::string data; // with trailing /r/n stripped if any
    bool isStderr; // if the line is stderr
};

static int getCmdOutput(const char* cmd, std::vector<OutputLine>& out)
{
    namespace bp = boost::process;

    out.clear();

    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    bp::ipstream s_out, s_err;
    std::error_code ec;

    bp::child c(cmd, bp::std_err > s_err, bp::std_out > s_out, ec);
    if (ec)
        return -1;
    std::mutex mx, mx2;
    bool readingStdout = false;
    auto readFunc = [&]() {
        for (std::string line;;)
        {
            bool doStdout = false;
            {
                std::scoped_lock lock(mx2);
                if (!readingStdout)
                    doStdout = readingStdout = true;
            }
            bool res = !!std::getline(doStdout ? s_err : s_out, line);
            {
                std::scoped_lock lock(mx2);
                if (doStdout)
                    readingStdout = false;
            }
            if (!res)
                break;
            while (!line.empty() && (line.back() == '\r' || line.back() == '\n'))
                line.pop_back();

            std::scoped_lock lock(mx);
            out.emplace_back();
            out.back().data.swap(line);
            out.back().isStderr = doStdout;
        }
        };
    std::thread th(readFunc); // read stdout/stderr from async thread
    readFunc(); // read stdout/stderr
    c.wait();
    th.join();
    return c.exit_code();
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<OutputLine> out;
    int ret = getCmdOutput("test-exe.exe", out);

    for (const auto& s : out)
        printf("%s\n", s.data.c_str());

    printf("test-exe.exe return: %d", ret);
}


Why is it important that output to cout and cerr get printed in a specific order? I have a hard time imagining a program where that matters (should matter).

just out of my curiosity, I wanted to mimic cmd.exe output

cmd.exe isn’t really reading the output from its child processes: their output goes directly to the console (“terminal emulator” in Unix parlance).  When nothing is redirected, stdout and stderr are the same file, and since stdout is line-buffered complete lines simply appear in the order that are written.
You can mostly get this behavior simply by using the same pipe for the child’s stdout and stderr (which is what 2>&1 does, but outside the command), but then it won’t be a terminal and stdout buffering becomes relevant.  The only real answer is to use a pseudoterminal, which is non-trivial on Windows.

I'm not aware about internal plumbing. Perhaps, it's the conhost.exe or whatever it is that does the job reading pipes and drawing text on the screen (instead of cmd.exe). Anyways, even with system("test-exe 2>&1") result isn't the same with my sample test-exe. I don't think that console plumbing uses something "hidden" to read stdout/stderr as data becomes available. Which is the reason for my post: seems like boost::process should be able to achieve similar output with proper/efficient reading of stdout/stderr pipes.

VS has developer terminal, which is a gui tab that can be used to execute/run commands using cmd line from visual studio. If I run my sample test-exe, output is properly ordered. The same is with msys2 console: If I run it all from under the msys2 the output is also correct. No matter what I do with boost::process output is ALWAYS not properly ordered. Is it because msys2 and vs dev powershell are both pseudoterminals?

Buffering is the most likely issue, yes: it's very common for it to produce out-of-order output between stdout and stderr.  It's still not good to have them as separate file descriptors, since then thread timing also contributes to the ordering possibilties.

In case of your sample: stderr usually flushes right away, so that error messages would be seen. However, no matter what you do, you always get correct output in windows console, but if you capture output yourself (instead of leaving it to be handled by terminal subsystem), then you end up with all kinds of issues. That's the issue
